# If statement executing regardless

Tags: python

I'm using the requests library in python to grab a webpage's text data, however this should only occur if a particular sentence is found, yet... it still does.

```
pageresult = requests.get(combo[0], headers=header).text
        
if "We're sorry, but the page you were looking for couldn't be found" or "Page not found" in pageresult:
    print('on page\n')
    print(combo[0])
    text_file = open("PAGERESULT.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(pageresult)
    text_file.close()
```

For some reason this `if` statement still executes, even though the conditions are not met.

Neither "We're sorry, but the page you were looking for couldn't be found" or "Page not found" are in the website text data, yet the statement still executes?

Comment: Hint: `bool("any non-empty string")` is True

Comment: ...and `True or "foo" in "bar"` is _also_ True.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh damnit i forgot the additional 'in pageresult'. Thanks

Comment: Also, minor side-note: Learn to use `with` statements for your file operations. `with open("PAGERESULT.txt", "w")
 as text_file: text_file.write(pageresult)` is no harder to type, avoids the need to explicitly call `close`, and guarantees the file is actually closed even in the event of an exception.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Haha i knew that was coming as i made the post, i normally would use a context manager, not sure why i didn't here!